Serverless Framework v3 custom-resource-existing-cup function Node16 is deprecated
I am using Serverless Framework (v3), and Node.js (v18). and it creates one lambda function (custom-resource-existing-cup) automatically if there is this line is added in the Cognito custom trigger lambda function.
existing: true
It's okay, but the problem is this lambda function is using Node 16, even I use Node 18.
I tried to change the Node.js version for this custom lambda function, but I couldn't, because it's generated automatically by Serverless Framework.
Is there anyway to solve this issue? Because it's deprecating soon.

The Lambda function for custom resources have nodejs16 runtime hardcoded.
https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/d0e3056b77ba295adb87ceeca9a49a26b315f083/lib/plugins/aws/custom-resources/index.js#L165-L179
const customResourceFunction = { 
   Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function', 
   Properties: { 
     Code: { 
       S3Bucket, 
       S3Key, 
     }, 
     FunctionName: absoluteFunctionName, 
     Handler, 
     MemorySize: 1024, 
     Runtime: 'nodejs16.x', 
     Timeout: 180, 
   }, 
   DependsOn: [], 
 }; 

I tried to edit the node_modules as this link, it works well.
https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/12133#issuecomment-1958961198
